# Includinq twig template php in javascript code

Tags: javascript, twig

I'm a junior developer and never created a full structure on my own.
Now that I try to realize a personal project I am facing some issues...
I choose to code in php, not using any framework, I use twig to create templates and until now I didn't face any trouble.

But here is the scenario : I have a page with 2 links (spans) and one div below. When i click on one, I want the content of a template to be displayed on the div below, it will be a full page with a lot of javascript, ajax calls and stuff, and same when clicking the other link but with another page content.

I tried this code :

```
<div>
    <h1> Home </h1>
    <span id="id1"> link 1 </span>
    <br/>
    <span id="id2"> link 2 </span>
    <div id="test_div"></div>    
</div>

<script>
$('#id1').click(function(){
    $('#test_div').html('hey');
});
$('#id2').click(function(){
        $('#test_div').html('<?php echo $twig->render("test.html"); ?>');
});
</script>
```

Here is the content on test.html :

```
<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<div id="test"> this is a test content </div>
```

The issue is, when coding this, it doesn't work, seems that the template is wrongly included, i don't really understand why, so am I doing something wrong , maybe it's not obvious to me but will be to someone more experimented...

I know i shouldn't use PHP in script so is it possible to combine one template toole for php and one for js ? How people do when they use php and want to dynamically change the content of a page/div once everyhting is loaded ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You can't run PHP in Javascript.  PHP runs on the server and the results are sent to the browser.  Have a look at [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  You'll need to change it to something like `$("#test_div").load("some-page.php");`

Comment: @Archer u are right and not at the same moment u aren't. This is first ran through the `twig` compiler. Anyway tying to use `php` inside `twig`-templates is not a good practise. @Yunie - any reason u can't fetch that resource with an  `ajax`-call? Also why don't u just `include` the 2nd template?

Comment: @DarkBee - `jQuery.load()` *is* an Ajax call.

Comment: @Archer The 2nd part was meant for OP

Comment: @DarkBee I understand that.  I'm pointing out to you that it's already been suggested ;)

Comment: @Archer u were editing your comment while I was posting/editing mine

Comment: I think it will happen in any case that I will need to use a template in js, is there anyway i could do it ? using another template tool for js ?

Comment: @DarkBee Not sure what you're trying to say.  I posted the url linking him to the `load()` method way before I finished editing the comment, so *it had already been suggested*. Okay?

Comment: Is it possible to combine one template toole for php and one for js ? How people do when they use php and want to dynamically change the content of a page/div once everyhting is loaded ?